Get too small executable when using arm-none-eabi-gcc to compile STM32 project
I am trying to compile a STM32 project to test USART performance. The project is almost fully generated by STM32CubeMX for STM32H743XI chip, then I just put some test code into the main function. But when I ran the make command, the compiler gave me too small ELF and BIN files (maybe they were broken?). The same code on STM32F407 chip results in a good executable and it can run on MCU normally.
By contrast, I wrote a simple code to toggle LED on the board. This time the compiler gave a normal executable.
Version:

System: Arch Linux
arm-none-eabi-gcc: 14.1.0
STM32CubeMX: 6.11.0
STM32CubeH7: commit d76ccdf6165bdf31d3718ae4722aa23bd15cc582

Reproduce:

Download STM32H7 drivers on https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeH7.
Create a new project on STM32CubeMX, then choose STM32H743XI chip.
In "Pinout & Configuration", set "High Speed Clock (HSE)" to "Crystal/Ceramic Resonator", set "Power Regulator Voltage Scale" to "Scale 0".
In "Pinout & Configuration", set "USART2" mode to "Asynchronous".
In "Clock Configuration", set "Input frequency" to "25MHz", set "SYSCLK" to "480MHz", then resolve clock issues.
In "Project Manager", set "Toolchain/IDE" to "Makefile".
In "Project Manager", choose "Copy only the necessary library files", then click "GENERATE CODE".
Open project folder, add arm-none-eabi libraries to "C_INCLUDES".
Open "main.c", add following code to private function prototypes:

#ifdef __GNUC__
#define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int __io_putchar(int ch)
#define GETCHAR_PROTOTYPE int __io_getchar(void)
#else
#define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int fputc(int ch, FILE *f)
#define GETCHAR_PROTOTYPE int fgetc(FILE *f)
#endif

PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE
{
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)&ch, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  return ch;
}

GETCHAR_PROTOTYPE
{
  uint8_t ch = 0;

  /* Clear the Overrun flag just before receiving the first character */
  __HAL_UART_CLEAR_OREFLAG(&huart2);

  /* Wait for reception of a character on the USART RX line and echo this
   * character on console */
  HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, (uint8_t *)&ch, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  // HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)&ch, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  return ch;
}


Add following code before the infinite while loop:

printf("Welcome to Lab USART_Test!\n");


Run make in the root of project folder.

Result:

Content of "Makefile": https://pastebin.com/SRfgdjFh
COntent of "main.c": https://pastebin.com/Zr9zkVBq
Output of make: https://pastebin.com/wnC1AKFX
Size of output ELF and BIN files: 6.1 kbytes and 96 bytes, respectively.
Output of openocd (to download program to MCU flash):

Error: [stm32h7x.cpu0] clearing lockup after double fault
[stm32h7x.cpu0] halted due to debug-request, current mode: Handler HardFault
xPSR: 0x00000003 pc: 0xf3af4804 msp: 0x4c05b4f0

Any reply is highly appreciated.

Please add your results directly into the question. External links might go stale or cannot be opened by everyone.

Make output has this linker error: ...warning: cannot find entry symbol Reset_Handler. I don't think this is how you intend it? It says further on defaulting to 08000000, so it seems it treats vector table like executable code because of that. Basically, some chaos going on here. You should provide a proper reset handler.
